# REGEX and replacing strings that has numeric as identity

Tags: regex

I have list of strings that i look for in a string
Param1      with value 0
Param2      with value 1
Param3      with value 0
Param4      with value 1
Param5      with value 0
Param6      with value 1
Param7      with value 0
Param8      with value 1
Param9      with value 0
Param10      with value 1
Param11      with value 0

the string is (for example):

```
Param1+Param2+Param3+Param4+Param5+Param6+Param7+Param8+Param9+Param10+Param11
```

if i replace Param1 it will give me this result
**0**+Param2+Param3+Param4+Param5+Param6+Param7+Param8+Param9+**0**0+**0**1
how can i replace the Param with the right numeric near it?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to match it without the "+"?
A simple Regex would let you search for (Param1+). By doing this it won't match "Param10" or "Param11". Those are matched because they are Strings containing the group of characters you are searching for.
If you specify your group of characters further more by adding the "+" you can match only Param1.

But remember to add the "+" at the end of whatever you are replacing it for.
For example: Replace with "0+" not with "0"

I hope this simple approach solves your problem.

Comment: That was only an example. after Param(N) can be one of these: +,*,/,-,^,)

Comment: Fails if the param you are replacing comes last in the string